# Expanding $\frac{2x^2}{1+x^3}$ to series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

So I was doing some series expansion problems and stumbled upon this one ( the problem is from Pauls Online Notes )

$$f(x) = \frac{2x^2}{1+x^3}$$

The actual solution to this problem uses a different method then mine. Since this function is really seams nice for integration, i thought i could do:

$$h(x) = \int f(x) dx =\int \frac{2x^2}{1+x^3}dx = \frac{2}{3} \ln({1+x^3})$$

If we let $t=x^3$, and use Maclaurin series for $\ln{(1+t)}$ we have
$$\frac{2}{3} \ln({1+t}) = \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n} $$
No we can take the derivative part by part in  the radius of convergence we will get the original function series expansion:

$$f(x)= \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n-1} t^{n-1} =  \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n-1} (x^3)^{n-1}$$

But the solution from the course is :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}2(-1)^{n} x^{3n+2}$$

Where did i go wrong? :(
Thanks.

Comment: Differentiate $\displaystyle x\mapsto \frac{2}{3} \sum \limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left((-1)^{n-1} \frac{\left(\color{red}{x^3}\right)^n}{n}\right)$ again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intelligent question. The problem is that you first differentiate with respect to $t$, then substitute $t$ back for $x^3$. The correct approach is the reverse order: replace $t$ by $x^3$ and derive with respect to $x$. Otherwise, your solution is nice. Below you will find a slightly more direct one.

Assume $x \ne 0$. Then

$$\frac {2 x^2} {1+x^3} = \frac 1 x \frac {2 x^3} {1+x^3} = 2 - \frac 2 {1+x^3} = \frac 2 x - \frac 2 x \sum \limits _{n=0} ^\infty (-1)^n x^{3n} = - \frac 2 x \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^n x^{3n} = \\ -\frac 2 x \sum \limits _{m=0} ^\infty (-1)^{m+1} x^{3m+3} = 2 \sum \limits _{m=0} ^\infty (-1)^m x^{3m+2} .$$

All computations are assumed to happen where they are defined (i.e. inside the interval of convergence).

Finally, you can see the this equality is also valid for $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Consider the series of $\frac 1{1+y}$. Replace $y$ by $x^3$ and multiply the result by $2x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: to get the answer you need, you need to convert back to $x$ before you differentiate, because you have integrated with respect to $x$ and differentiated with respect to $t$ and these are not inverse operations.